# hmac key and salt length

Tags: security, hash, hmac, sha, hmacsha1

I'm using hmac sha1 to sign a userid which is passed to a third party service.
The same secret is used for all users and the salt is unique for each user.

```
token = userid : timestamp+2hours : hmac(userid : timestamp+2hours, salt+secret)
token_hex = hex(hash)
```

Will hmac work for short strings? userid:timestamp can be for example 12:1304985212
Does the order of salt and secret matters? (salt+secret vs secret+salt)
What should be the shared secret length and what should be the salt length?
Can I use the same secret to also sign messages between the server and the remote service or is it better to generate a separate secret?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should calculate hmac(salt : userid : timestamp+2hours, secret) and transmit salt : userid : timestamp+2hours : hash.
Purpose of salt here is to make plaintext longer and not repeating, so it better be appended to plaintext, not secret.

If you really want to change secret, do hmac(userid : timestamp+2hours, hash(salt : secret)), it will make one-time secret look more like random number.

Comment: adding the salt to the plaintext part makes sense. Does it matter if I transmit the salt or pass it offline between the server and the remote service like the secret? Is there a chance that the secret might be cracked? Your second example protect from that but maybe you mean: hmac(salt:userid:timestamp, hash(salt:secret)). Do I really need hmac in this case, or is it enough to have sha1(userid:timestamp:salt:secret)?

Comment: You can't pass salt offline in useful way: salt MUST be random and used only once, changing with every message. So you can only get it from random number generator before use and transmit with data. There is nothing secret in salt until it changes every time. Actually, if you send no more then one message every second, you do not need separate salt at all: hash(timestamp) would suffice. Secret can't be extracted from HMAC result, your only risk is getting it stolen from server. Second example just makes HMAC nonrepeating by giving new secret every time, not new plaintext.

Comment: what's wrong with using just timestamp instead of hash(timestamp) as the salt and usersecret+globalsecret to prevent rainbow attack?

Comment: If you will use separate salt - nothing wrong here. Hash(timestamp) is only for using it as salt: it can't be bad to spread 1-bit difference in timestamp sequence over long hash result.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment. timestamp as salt is good or bad? hash(timestamp) as salt is better?

Comment: Timestamp as a salt is ok if 1) there is no two messages with same userid and timestamp; 2) you are using hash(timestamp) as salt.